# Building open street routing machine (osrm)

Tags: routes, ubuntu-12.04, openstreetmap, osmosis, osrm

I'm doing a project on openstreetmap, thus for the purpose of implementing routing mechanism I tried to implement osrm referring [1](https://github.com/Project-OSRM/osrm-backend/wiki/Building-OSRM#fetch-the-source), but when I tried out `mkdir -p build; cd build; cmake ..`, I got an error saying:

> "CMake Error: The source directory "/home/user1" does not appear to
>   contain CMakeLists.txt".

What should I do to resolve this!

Comment: The instruction says to run `cmake ..`, but you've said you tried running `cmake` (with no argument)?

Answer (score 5):

After running the git clone command, you first need to go to your cloned branch directory by typing `cd osrm-backend/`. After that continue with `mkdir -p build; cd build; cmake ..; make`.

Here's the directory layout assumed by cmake, to make things a bit clearer.

```
/home/user1
/home/user1/osrm-backend
/home/user1/osrm-backend/build
```